# QGIS Action on layer postselect object

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, actions

I'm using QGIS 3.10 LTR. In my project I have a point layer (location of pictures) with 3 different actions (open file, open folder, open html). This works fine for me.
To this layer I add time by time new objects (new pictures) which are sometime very close to next object.
When I select the layer and the action and click to on an object then sometimes opens a menu with numbers. I think this are the object id's. Is it possible to show an attribute an not the id?

I searched in the settings an here, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: it looks like a bug. The "display name" should be used. You may want to [report](https://github.com/qgis/qgis/issues) it

Comment: I don´t think this is a bug. The objects are to near to each other, that Qgis want to know which one should be opened. So it shows the ID I think. I want, that it shows the content of an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Display in properties windows. Change Display expression/name (mention in comment's) to desired value.